# Transfer a program from one computer to another without an installer

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems, file-transfer, data-transfer

I have an ancient windows 2000 laptop linked to medical equipment, but I'm uneasy about running such old hardware with a vulnerable, antiquidated OS. I'm looking for guidance for either transferring the software that reads the equipment's data to a more modern machine, or virtualizing the old machine. I'd prefer the former solution, but I sense that it may be unfeasible. Any tips on how to move software and perhaps drivers from one machine to another?

Comment: You first should determine if the software will event run on a different version of Windows.  It could be as simple as copying the installation directory.  However, if the program uses the Windows registry you will likely encounter errors when running the application.   *The only way to determine what is required is to attempt to run it.*

Comment: Does the application appear in Programs and Features/add or remove programs? Maybe as one or more entries? Can you find out if the application entries for it are MSI based by checking for these under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\, and if 64-bit PC also under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ Can you see the application, if so what is the uninstallstring values for them, does it start msiexec?  Are we looking at a MSI based installer?

Comment: If the laptop does not connect to the internet this would require physical access to compromise the PC, and having this type of access will not help having the latest OS. Don't connect to the Internet Ever, and you are as safe as it gets.